# Indicating Gender in pos-Tags, Python

Tags: python-3.x, pos-tagger, french, treetagger

Am trying to Pos-Tag a french sentences with TreeTagger Wrapper, But it does not indicate the gender of the nouns

This is an example:

```
import treetaggerwrapper
import pprint

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')

var1 = 'un garçon'
var2 = 'une fille'
var3 = 'ils jouent'

tags1 = tagger.tag_text(var1)
tags11= treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags1)

tags2 = tagger.tag_text(var2)
tags22= treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags2)

tags3 = tagger.tag_text(var3)
tags33= treetaggerwrapper.make_tags(tags3)
```

This is the output:

```
un garçon : [Tag(word='un', pos='DET:ART', lemma='un'), Tag(word='garçon', pos='NOM', lemma='garçon')]
une fille : [Tag(word='une', pos='DET:ART', lemma='un'), Tag(word='fille', pos='NOM', lemma='fille')]
ils jouent : [Tag(word='ils', pos='PRO:PER', lemma='il'), Tag(word='jouent', pos='VER:pres', lemma='jouer')]
```

Is there anyway I can get the **grammatical characteristics** in the tag like:

**The gender**( GND='F' or GND='M')

**The person** ( Pers='3Pl' or VER:pres+3+Pl)'in the third sentence (verb and pronoun))?

Advance Thanks

Comment: Pre-trained TreeTagger model doesn't do grammatical INDEX (i.e. PERSON, NUMBER, GENDER).

Comment: Try https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-fr